# Cloudfront not configuring Magento 2 CORS Policy error

Tags: magento2, cloudfront-cdn

> I am getting error
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on Magento 2 website.Although i add
>   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'.But still its not enable
>   it.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bneg6.png)

[image]